# How to avoid charset=utf-8 from Content-Type?

Tags: python, json, aiohttp

It is a common case to return JSON data in response, `aiohttp.web` provides a shortcut for returning JSON – `aiohttp.web.json_response()`:

```
def handler(request):
    data = {'some': 'data'}
    return web.json_response(data)
```

The shortcut method returns `aiohttp.web.Response` instance so we can for example set cookies before returning it from handler.

But my curl request returns me `Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8`, but I need just `application/json`, how to avoid `charset=utf-8`?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to avoid `charset=utf-8` in your content type? If you don't specify it, the fallback (default value) will be `ISO-8859-1` as of [W3C](https://www.w3.org/International/articles/http-charset/index).

And actual answer to your question: current aiohttp version doesn't support changing a charset with `json_response` shortcut function. Even using `aiohttp.web.Response` directly without specifying a charset would add `charset=utf8` to your response's *Content-Type*. You can change charset but no omit it (unless `text` argument of `aiohttp.web.Response.__init__` is set *None*).

To *change* charset using `json_response` you can do something like this:

```
web.json_response(
    data,
    content_type=None,
    headers={aiohttp.hdrs.CONTENT_TYPE: 'application/json; charset=ISO-8859-1'},
)
```

or use `functools.partial` to don't repeat this longish function call every time:

```
my_json_resp = partial(
    web.json_response, 
    content_type=None,
    headers={aiohttp.hdrs.CONTENT_TYPE: 'application/json; charset=ISO-8859-1'},
)

# later in your app
return my_json_resp(data)
```

You can have a look at the sources of `json_response` [here](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/aiohttp/web_response.html#json_response) and `Response.__init__` [here](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/aiohttp/web_response.html#Response) to check it yourself.

Comment: The reason we want to avoid it is because it runs into a bug in Apache that thinks it's invalid, and it also runs into a bug in Azure's default filtering that thinks the request is malformed that returns `403 Forbidden`.  So we have to workaround buggy web-servers that we don't control (and for whom getting them to turn off all Azure attach protection is more effort than it's worth)